# How do I chain commands on the console?

Tags: command-line, bash

In `bash`, I sometimes want to run several commands in serial and don't want to wait for them to finish before I type the new ones.  So I do something like this:

`cmd1; cmd2; cmd3`

Unfortunately, one of the commands might fail.  In that case, I'd like to stop.  Is there an easy way to do this, but make it so that I only keep running the commands if the previous command had a 0 exit code?

Comment: Here is a [great answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/194972) from the Unix SE.

Comment: Sometimes I forget, the semicolon doesn't care about success or failure...

`command1 ; command2`

First command1 is run, and once it has finished, command2 runs.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `&&` operator,

```
cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3
```

---

In shellscripting, `&&` and `||` operators are modelled after optimized implementation of logical operators in C. `&&` means AND operator, and `||` means OR. Unix is tightly related to C, and in C, the second operand of logical operators isn't evaluated if the result is already known from the first operand. E.g. `"false && x"` is `false` for any `x`, so there is no need to evaluate `x` (especially if `x` is a function call); similarly for `"true || x"`. This is also called **[short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) semantics**.

And in Unix, it is traditional to interpret commands' return values as "successful completion" truth values: exit code 0 means `true` (success), nonzero means `false` (failure). So, when the first command in `cmd1 && cmd2` returns `"false"` (nonzero exit status, which indicates failure), the compound command's status is known: failure. So overall interpretation of `cmd1 && cmd2`  may be: "execute `cmd1`, AND THEN, if it didn't fail, `cmd2`". Which is what you basically want in your question.

Similarly with OR: `cmd1 || cmd2` can be interpreted as "execute `cmd1`, OR IF it fails, `cmd2`".

---

*Protip:* for longer chains of `&&`, consider putting **`set -e`** in your script. It basically changes the semicolon `;` into `&&`, with a couple of special cases.

Comment: +1 for explaining `||`

Comment: can you chain whatever the status of the first command is? (success or failure)

Comment: @HugoTrentesaux what do you mean?.. The success/failure result or `A || B` is just the same as the [short-circuiting] logical **A OR B**. `A || B` is *success* when `A` was *success*, or when `A` was *failure* but `B` was *success*; and `A || B` is *failure* when `A` was *failure* and `B` was `failure`. Similarly for `&&`, it follows logical AND.

Comment: In the shell context, how can I execute A and then B no matter if A fails or succeeds?

Comment: @HugoTrentesaux that's what the plain regular `;` (or newline) does by default. `set -e` will turn `;` into `&&`, roughly speaking. `set +e` [the default] turns `A; B` into what you say: run `A`, then no-matter-what run `B`.

Answer (score 13):

"Chaining Commands an grouping them"

```
ping 192.168.0.1 || { echo "ping not successful"; exit 1; }
```

pings, only if not successful, executes the chained group of commands in brackets.

**Attention:**

The list has to be terminated with a ";".

There must be blank spaces between brackets and the grouped commands!

Answer (score 6):

Simply with the `&&` operator. For instance:

```
cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3
```

If one of the commands fails (returns an exit value other than 0), the other commands won't run.